# Parsing JSON objects inside object with GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse this link- [football data org seasons](http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/)

It has some objects inside a object. For the internal objects I made a class named Season-

```
public class Season {
private int id;
private String caption, league, year;
private int currentMatchday, numberOfMatchday, numberOfTeams, numberOfGames;
private String lastUpdated;

public Season(){

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Season{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", caption='" + caption + '\'' +
            ", league='" + league + '\'' +
            ", year='" + year + '\'' +
            ", currentMatchday=" + currentMatchday +
            ", numberOfMatchday=" + numberOfMatchday +
            ", numberOfTeams=" + numberOfTeams +
            ", numberOfGames=" + numberOfGames +
            ", lastUpdated='" + lastUpdated + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

This class works fine as it visits internal object links which has key,value pair and I have named my class fields accordingly. For example- when I visit this [specific season](http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/394), I can easily call`Season s = gs.fromJson(json.toString(), Season.class);`

But how do I parse all the objects inside that top level object(the first link)? I tried with ArrayList, but it gives error saying expected BEGIN_ARRAY but found BEGIN_OBJECT. I understood it because in JSON we have objects not an array. So how do I do it?

Comment: can try  `gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Season>>() {}.getType());` or `gson.fromJson(json, Season[].class);`

Comment: @varren Thank you very much you solved my problem. `gson.fromJson(json, Season[].class);` This code worked.